# Silhouette Coefficient of HAC if k = 1

Tags: python-2.7, cluster-analysis, evaluation, hierarchical-clustering, silhouette

How to calculate value of Silhouette Coefficient of HAC clustering if `k=1` (so, all data in 1 cluster)? Silhouette coefficient has range `-1` until `1`, but for singleton (`k=maximum`) (cluster that has only 1 data) the Silhouette Coefficient is `0`. Is it `0` for silhouette coefficient of `k=1` or is it `-1` or `1`? Formula of silhouette coefficient is
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9NHL.jpg).

`SC(i) = (b(i)-a(i))/max(a(i), b(i))`

`a(i) = Average distance of object with other object in one cluster.`

`b(i) = Minimum Average distance of object with other object in other cluster.`

*sorry for my bad english

Comment: Any perticular software ( r, python, c++ etc)  you are using, add that tag with your question to increase the reachability.

Comment: python-2.7. Thank you

Comment: Pyhton 2.7 is on its way out start using version python3, anyways Good luck

Answer (score 0):

The silhouette coefficient is **not defined** for a single cluster only.

So the proper value would be undefined, although I suggest to use 0 then. Because 0 is the value suggested by the authors for one-element clusters, where the Silhouette value also would be undefined.

And the notion of a negative Silhouette is that the points are closer to another cluster. For a one cluster solution, that does not hold. This the value should be 0. Or undefined.

Comment: Thank you. Can you show me the reference, ex. journal or publication. I can't find the reference

Comment: The reference should be in Wikipedia. Likely the seminal Kaufman and Rousseew book.